# What's the input dimensionality of this layer? (How many columns/features does the input data set have)

Tags: python

What's the input dimensionality of this layer?

(How many columns/features does the input data set have)

```
model.add(LSTM(42,input_shape=(23,5),return_sequences=True))
```

Comment: You can see it there itself, input_shape = (23,5).

Answer (score 1):

The dimensions of the input data should be 5 features and of length 23 for each piece of data.